# Sequelize Subqueries

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

in this case i want to find the total prepare time for each order according the orderId, but when i write like this it only shows 1 result which is the first one,

```
 let prepareOrder = await OrderItem.findAll({
          
    where: {
            options: null,
          },
    
          attributes: ["orderId"],
    
          include: [
            {
              model: Item,
              attributes: [
                [
                  sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("prepareTime")),
                  "totalPrepareTime",
                ],
    
              ],
    
            },
          ],
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rum `SUM()` on the outer query. When you run it on the inner query it is returning a single row and then doing a `JOIN` which is why you only get one row.

```js
const prepareOrder = await OrderItem.findAll({
  attributes: [
    "orderId",
    // get the summary at the OrderItem for each related Item
    [
      sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("item.prepareTime")),
      "totalPrepareTime",
    ],
  ],
  // include Item but no attributes for performance
  include: {
    model: Item,
    attributes: [],
  },
  where: {
    options: null,
  },
});
```